# QML QComboBox.find() can not find element by text

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qcombobox

In QML I have a QComboBox:

```
ComboBox {
    id: myCBox
    model: [ "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "3.5", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]
 }
```

When I try to find an element in the ComboBox by text it returns -1.

Log with this:

```
console.log(myCBox.find("5"))
```

And it outputs -1 (which means not found).

[QML QComboBox documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html)

Comment: When do you call that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check, when do you the call `myCBox.find`, look at this code:

```
ComboBox {
    id: myCBox
    model: [ "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "3.5", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("After this line it should work fine.");
    }

    Item {
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("myCBox is not completed:", myCBox.find("5"));
        }
    }
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("myCBox here must be completed:", myCBox.find("5"));
}
```

and the output:

```
myCBox is not completed: -1
After this line it should work fine.
myCBox must be completed: 6
```

Uppon creation, `Component` creates all items and then arranging them in a tree. From the most inner object, it updates properties and bindings to the most overrided value and calls attached method `Component.onCompleted`.

Comment: I was able to avoid doing it at startup, but your answer have value and answers my question.